# cascade select with parent, child and sub child drop down boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I am creating a form using django 1.8. in this form I am using cascade select on three fields type, subtype and category.

Type is the parent of subtype.

subtype is the parent of category.

When I change the value in the type drop-down box the subtype drop down box is disabled but the category drop down box is still active. I am wondering how to disable the category drop down box as well.

The category drop down box is disabled when the subtype drop down box is changed by the user.

cascade select

```
CascadeSelect({
    use_ajax: true,
    url: "{{ request.get_full_path }}", // The url for the ajax function
    parent: "id_project_type", // Name of the parent field in forms.py
    child: "id_sub_type", // Name of the child field in forms.py
    selected_child: "{{ selected_sub_type }}", // Sent from views.py
    empty_label_init: "Select a type first",
    empty_label_selected: "--- Please select ---",
    disable_child: true
});

CascadeSelect({
    use_ajax: true,
    url: "{{ request.get_full_path }}", // The url for the ajax function
    parent: "id_sub_type", // Name of the parent field in forms.py
    child: "id_category", // Name of the child field in forms.py
    selected_child: "{{ selected_sub_type }}", // Sent from views.py
    empty_label_init: "Select a type first",
    empty_label_selected: "--- Please select ---",
    disable_child: true
});
```